# What is the most efficient way to do a row by row validation of a csv file in-browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, csv

I have to check csv files against some specific rules to make sure every single row is validated. For example, a `Quantity` column must contain `numbers` only. If a single record contains a string, then the csv is rejected.

I found http://papaparse.com/ which I think is a very good library for parsing the csv data. Off the back of that, I can use the parsed data to check row by row.

I wanted to get ideas on what's the best way I can validate a csv file of 50,000 rows against 10 rules without crashing the browser?

Comment: Read row-by-row using the HTML5 File API. That way you never need to load the entire file into memory.

Comment: large loop, you probably want to look into a web worker

Comment: Found a perfect example of how to do this: [LineReader](https://github.com/mgmeyers/LineReader)

Comment: @mathewHerbst HTML5 File is really useful and LineReader library helped as well. Thanks